# wsdl.exe ignores complexType containing a single array element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, complextype, wsdl.exe

I want to have the following structure in my WSDL (leaving out namespaces)

```html
<complexType name="NotesResponseType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Notes" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="Response">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      .
      .
      <xs:element name="Notes" type="tns:NotesResponseType" minOccurs="0"/>
      .
      .
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

so that i get the following structure in my C# code

```cs
Response response; 
response.Notes = new NotesResponseType(); 
response.Notes.Notes = new string[1];
```

but wsdl.exe seems to ignore the complex type 'NotesResponseType' altogether i.e response.Notes is an array of string , and not of type NotesResponseType as i would expect.  is there a way to tell wsdl.exe to not do this?